# Pandas - min and max of a column up until each line

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'group': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2}, 'year': {0: 2007, 1: 2008, 2: 2009, 3: 2010, 4: 2006, 5: 2007, 6: 2008}, 'amount': {0: 2.0, 1: -4.0, 2: 5, 3: 7.0, 4: 8.0, 5: -10.0, 6: 12.0}}])

   group    year    amount
0   1       2007    2
1   1       2008    -4
2   1       2009    5
3   1       2010    7
4   2       2006    8
5   2       2007    -10
6   2       2008    12
```

I want to add min, max, number of years that amount is negative,number of years that amount is positive for each group, up until each year (inclusive). My ideal dataframe looks like this

```
   group    year    amount    min_utd    max_utd   no_n_utd    no_p_utd
0   1       2007    2           2           2         0           1
1   1       2008    -4         -4           2         1           1
2   1       2009    5          -4           5         1           2
3   1       2010    7          -4           7         1           3
4   2       2006    8           8           8         0           1
5   2       2007    -10        -10          8         1           1 
6   2       2008    12         -10          12        1           2
```

I am only aware of `agg` with which you can do for the whole group, or `rolling` when you do for a sliding window, but I dont know how to calculate from the beginning up to each line.

Comment: I think you are looking for cummin, cummax and cumsum.

Comment: How come `no_n_utd` are in negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.cummin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummin.html) and then [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) with comparing by `lt` (`<`) and `ge` (>=):

```
df[['min_utd','max_utd']] = df.groupby('group')['amount'].agg(['cummin','cummax'])
df['no_n_utd'] = df['amount'].lt(0).astype(int).groupby(df['group']).cumsum()
df['no_p_utd'] = df['amount'].ge(0).astype(int).groupby(df['group']).cumsum()

print (df)
   group  year  amount  min_utd  max_utd  no_n_utd  no_p_utd
0      1  2007       2        2        2         0         1
1      1  2008      -4       -4        2         1         1
2      1  2009       5       -4        5         1         2
3      1  2010       7       -4        7         1         3
4      2  2006       8        8        8         0         1
5      2  2007     -10      -10        8         1         1
6      2  2008      12      -10       12         1         2
```

Another solution with same principe but custom function:

```
def f(x):
   a = x.cummin()
   b = x.cummax()
   c = x.lt(0).cumsum()
   d = x.ge(0).cumsum()
   return pd.DataFrame({'min_utd':a, 'max_utd':b, 'no_n_utd':c, 'no_p_utd':d})

df = df.join(df.groupby('group')['amount'].apply(f))
print (df)
   group  year  amount  min_utd  max_utd  no_n_utd  no_p_utd
0      1  2007       2        2        2         0         1
1      1  2008      -4       -4        2         1         1
2      1  2009       5       -4        5         1         2
3      1  2010       7       -4        7         1         3
4      2  2006       8        8        8         0         1
5      2  2007     -10      -10        8         1         1
6      2  2008      12      -10       12         1         2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
grp = df.groupby('group')
df.assign(
    min_utd = grp['amount'].cummin(),
    max_utd = grp['amount'].cummax(),
    no_n_utd = grp.apply(lambda g: g['amount'].lt(0).cumsum()).values,
    no_p_utd = grp.apply(lambda g: g['amount'].gt(0).cumsum()).values
)
```

Output:

```
   group  year  amount  min_utd  max_utd  no_n_utd  no_p_utd
0      1  2007     2.0      2.0      2.0         0         1
1      1  2008    -4.0     -4.0      2.0         1         1
2      1  2009     5.0     -4.0      5.0         1         2
3      1  2010     7.0     -4.0      7.0         1         3
4      2  2006     8.0      8.0      8.0         0         1
5      2  2007   -10.0    -10.0      8.0         1         1
6      2  2008    12.0    -10.0     12.0         1         2
```